# String cleanup and substring replacement

Tags: sas

I have a table with 100k + rows.

I'm trying to remove all instance of several sub-strings from one of the fields.

The method I found so far basically calls tranwrd for every offending sub-string.

There are three in the example below, but in the actual data sets there are 
quite a few more.

```
data mytable;
infile datalines delimiter=':' truncover;
informat myfield $50. someval 3.;
input myfield someval;
datalines;
some value xx abc:10
another values:15
random stuff ccc:1
more stuff xx:2
example abc:44
foo abc bar:55
sub xx string:11
;
run;

proc sql;
    update mytable set myfield = strip(tranwrd(myfield,'abc',''));

    update mytable set myfield = strip(tranwrd(myfield,'ccc',''));

    update mytable set myfield = strip(tranwrd(myfield,'xx',''));
quit;
```

Is there was to get the same done with a single statement ?

I.e. given a full list of strings to delete, delete them all.

something along the lines of:

```
update mytable
set myfield = somefunction(myfield,/'abc','ccc','xx'/,'')
```

Thank you

With some more poking around, came up with below:

```
data mytable2;
set mytable;
n_myfield = myfield;
length word $50;
do word = 'abc','ccc','xx';
    n_myfield = tranwrd(n_myfield,word,'');
end;
    n_myfield = compbl(n_myfield);
drop word;
run;
```

does the trick without nesting (I really don't want to nest 10-15 tranwrd calls) or multiple nearly identical update statements.

regex is something I was hoping to use

Comment: `strip(tranwrd(tranwrd(myfield,'abc''),'ccc',''))`?

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to avoid nesting tranwrd calls.

Comment: You can use data step: `data mytable;
set mytable;
myfield = tranwrd(myfield,'abc','');
myfield = tranwrd(myfield,'ccc','');
myfield = tranwrd(myfield,'xx','');
myfield = strip(myfield);
run;`

Comment: There's also regular expressions ([`prxchange`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1vz3ljudbd756n19502acxazevk.htm)), but that requires converting your patterns to valid regular expressions.

Comment: The [compress](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0fcshr0ir3h73n1b845c4aq58hz.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p1v3kt0k9xvlwjn1gvwne2mwuk6f) function is also better for removing characters instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with regular expressions by concatenating the strings using the pipe character '|' which means "OR" in regular expressions:

```
myField = prxChange("s/abc|ccc|xx//",-1,trim(myField));
```

It is especially handy if you are trying to remove whole words, which is not easy with tranwrd, in this case you just change the regex to:

```
myField = prxChange("s/\b(abc|ccc|xx)\b\s?//",-1,trim(myField));
```

Where \b means word border (anything that is not a letter/number/underscore) and \s? part takes care of a possible extra space after the removed word.
It will change

```
"abcd abc ccc xx abccccxx"
```

to

```
"abcd abccccxx"
```

But as noted by Nickolay it works fine, until you have metacharacters in your string: {}^$@.|*+?\ and the character used to mark borders of regex, in this example it is / (you can change s/.../.../ to s#..#...# or s$..$..$ if you like). When you have them, you either manually escape them with \, e.g., the line below removes strings "abc", "$c\c", "x.":

```
myField = prxChange("s/abc|\$c\\c|xx//",-1,trim(myField));
```

Or run apply additional regex, which will escape all special characters:

```
length wordsToRemove $200;
retain wordsToRemove 'abc|ccc|xx|$pec@lW()rd';

if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    * This does not change, so set it once;
    wordsToRemove=prxChange('s/([\Q{}[]()^.*+?\E\$\@\\\/])/\\$1/', -1,strip(wordsToRemove));
end;
myField=prxChange('s/'|| strip(wordsToRemove) || '//', -1, trim(myField));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just read each word and evaluate whether to keep it or discard it.

```
data mytable;
  input someval myfield $50. ;
datalines;
10 some value xx abc
15 another values
1 random stuff ccc
2 more stuff xx
44 example abc
55 foo abc bar
11 sub xx string
;

data want ;
  set mytable ;
  length i 8 word n_myfield $50 ;
  drop i word ;
  do i =1 to countw(myfield,' ');
    word=scan(myfield,i,' ');
    if not findw('abc ccc xx',trim(word),' ') then n_myfield=catx(' ',n_myfield,word);
  end;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    someval    myfield              n_myfield

 1        10      some value xx abc    some value
 2        15      another values       another values
 3         1      random stuff ccc     random stuff
 4         2      more stuff xx        more stuff
 5        44      example abc          example
 6        55      foo abc bar          foo bar
 7        11      sub xx string        sub string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do more or less the same thing via regex:

```
data mytable;
    modify mytable;
    myfield = strip(prxchange('s/abc|ccc|xx//',-1,myfield)));
    replace;
run;
```

For reasons that remain unclear to me, this leaves you with 2 spaces when a matching word in between two other words is removed, whereas your original code leaves three. However, I suspect that this probably doesn't matter for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions is a simple and efficient approach, do loop is other approach as you mentioned, but with array.

```
data mytable2;
set mytable;
n_myfield = myfield;
array var (3) $10  _temporary_ ('abc','ccc','xx');
do i=1 to 3;
    n_myfield = tranwrd(n_myfield,strip(var(i)),'');
end;
n_myfield = compbl(n_myfield);
drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A single pass over the set of removal targets is not necessarily sufficient.
A robust reduction would require multiple passes until a full traversal caused no replacements.

Here is an example Proc DS2 step that defines a reusable `cleaner` method and uses it in a `data` program:

```
data have;
  infile datalines delimiter=':' truncover;
  informat myfield $50. someval 3.;
  input myfield someval;
datalines;
some value xx abc:10
another values:15
random stuff ccc:1
more stuff xx:2
example abc:44
foo abc bar:55
sub xx string:11
cabxxccc what to do?:123
xacccbcx funky chicken:456
;
run;

proc DS2 libs=WORK;

  package cleaner / overwrite=yes;

    method _remove ( 
        varchar(200) haystack
      , varchar(200) needles[*]
    )
    returns varchar(200);

      declare int i L P ;
      declare int removal_count;
      declare varchar(200) needle;

      do while (length ( haystack ) > 0);
        removal_count = 0;
        do i = 1 to dim(needles);

          needle = needles[i];
          L = lengthc (needle);
          P = index (haystack, needle);

          if L > 0 and P > 0 then do;
            haystack = tranwrd(haystack,needle,'');
            removal_count + 1;
          end;
        end;

        if removal_count = 0 then leave;
      end;

      return haystack;
    end;
  endpackage;

  data want / overwrite=yes;
    declare package cleaner c();
    declare varchar(20) targets[3];
    method init ();
      targets := ('abc', 'ccc', 'xx');
      put 'NOTE: INIT:' targets[*]=;
    end;
    method run ();
      set have;
      put myfield= ;
      myfield = c._remove(myfield, targets);
      put myfield= ;
      put;
    end;
  run;
quit;
```

Log

```
NOTE: INIT: targets[1]=abc targets[2]=ccc targets[3]=xx
myfield=some value xx abc
myfield=some value

myfield=another values
myfield=another values

myfield=random stuff ccc
myfield=random stuff

myfield=more stuff xx
myfield=more stuff

myfield=example abc
myfield=example

myfield=foo abc bar
myfield=foo  bar

myfield=sub xx string
myfield=sub  string

myfield=cabxxccc what to do?
myfield=cab what to do?

myfield=xacccbcx funky chicken
myfield= funky chicken
```